# Magento 2 to translation of variable is not working in cart page

Tags: magento2, cart

I'm working on Magento 2.2.3 CE.

I have faced one issue on the cart page while applying coupon code.

The coupon code is applied properly. But cart summary it's showing like **Discount (%1)** instead of **Discount (coupon description)**

I have cross-checked the core file code

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Quote/Address/Total/ShippingDiscount.php

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function fetch(Quote $quote, Total $total): array
{
    $result = [];
    $amount = $total->getDiscountAmount();

    if ($amount != 0) {
        $description = (string)$total->getDiscountDescription() ?: '';
        $result = [
            'code' => DiscountCollector::COLLECTOR_TYPE_CODE,
            'title' => strlen($description) ? __('Discount (%1)', $description) : __('Discount'),
            'value' => $amount
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

On line number 95, the %1 will be replaced by value of description.

While debugging this code, I have confirmed the *$description* contains the value ( coupon code description).

But it returns an output like below.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `__('Discount %1', $description)`

Comment: No. It's not working. It's showing like **Discount %1** in frontend